# Obscure Rotation Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

The points of the shape after the shear are $(-0.25, 1)$, $(1.75, 1)$, $(0.25, -1)$, $(-1.75, -1)$. Other than that the only other information given is that the vertical edges of the original shaded square have become horizontal (parallel to the x-axis).

[image]
I've calculated that the Shear Matrix is:

```
|x + 0.75y|
|    y    |
```

But I don't understand how we're supposed to know what the Rotation Matrix is with the given data.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: Why is your shear matrix a vector?  Don't you mean that your shear matrix should be $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0.75 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Check where a vertical vector (say $(0,1)$) maps to under the shear transformation.  Find the angle between it and the positive $x$-axis.  The negative of that angle (because you're turning it clockwise) is the one you will need to plug into the [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Comment: Sorry, that was just bad syntax on my part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slope of the formerly vertical edges after the shear is clearly $\frac{1}{0.75},$
that is, $\frac 43.$
These sides therefore are at an angle $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac43\right)$
counterclockwise from the direction of the $x$-axis.

You therefore need to rotate those sides (and therefore you need to rotate the whole figure)
by an angle that reduces the angle they make to the $x$-axis
from  $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac43\right)$ to zero.

So you need the rotation matrix for a clockwise rotation by $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac43\right)$
(or equivalent angle), or a counterclockwise rotation by $-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac43\right).$

I suspect the $\frac43$ slope was chosen because it leads to 
particularly nice values of the sine and cosine that you will need.

Comment: I never would have figured that out, I wish I could see these things as clearly as you